# C++ pattern strategy initialization

Tags: c++, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I'm developing a class has decided to split it into independent strategies. Something like this:

```
template<class Strategy1, class Strategy2, class Strategy3>
class SomeClass : public ...
{
public:
    SomeClass()
    {
        obj1 = new Strategy1 // and etc initialize member class
    }

   void run()
    {
        // do something work with obj1, obj2, obj3
    }
    ...
private:
    Strategy1 Obj1;
    Strategy2 Obj2;
    Strategy3 Obj3;
};
```

The problem is that all the specific classes of strategies are trivial constructor, that is all initialized differently.

```
class Strategy1
{
public:
    Strategy1(int, int, int);
    ...
};

class Strategy2
{
public:
    Strategy2(int, double, std::vector&);
    ...
};
```

It turns out that if I'm only in the class initialization SomeClass I need to define a new SomeClass. What class and what should do initialization? Please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass those `Strategy` classes into the constructor and build them outside of your containing object. If you attempt to do it wherein the construction is hidden within another class's constructor, you bind the implementation in a very hard manner.

```
 SomeClass(Strategy1 obj1, Strategy2 obj2, Strategy3 obj3){
```

Better yet, if you can use a TR1 function. Assuming no TR1, then I would suggest replacing those templates with calls to a [Boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/function/reference.html#header.boost.function_hpp).

Comment: Do not quite understand how to deal with std :: function

Comment: @Dima00782 They're nothing more than wrappers or containers for functions, function pointers, and function like objects (or as C++ would like to call them functors.) As long as the argument types match, they will accept any variety of the aforementioned types as valid arguments and treat them as such. You can use TR1 bind or Boost bind to increase the surface area of what is and isn't allowed. Look into these things. They're basically abstracting over the standard strategy pattern.

Comment: That is, you offer just curried parameters of each strategy and passed to the constructor has no parameters new strategies?

Comment: @Dima00782 I don't understand the question. Basically, I'm suggesting you abstract over the concrete types of your `Strategy` and pass those in through the constructor. You do not create the `Strategy` within the constructor, that leads to tight coupling. Tight coupling will hurt you in large projects.